# Помогите в настройке статики на nginx django

Tags: django, nginx

На сервере фронтенд и бэкенд сайта. Фронтенд на Vue и бэкенд на Django.
Не отдается статика с backenda ошибка 404.
Вот настройки nginx

```
server {
    root /home/django/django_venv/src/frontend/;
    index index.html;
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location /api/static/ {
        root /home/django/django_venv/src/static/;
    }
    location /api/media/ {
        root /home/djnago/django_venv/src/meida/;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
    }
    location @rewrites {
        rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html last;
    }
    location /api {
        include     proxy_params;
        proxy_pass  http://django_server;
    }
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/geografteach.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/geografteach.ru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Django

```
STATIC_URL = '/api/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
MEDIA_URL = '/api/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

Comment: А сами файлы в этих папках есть? `python manage.py collectstatic` делали? В settings.py прописано `DEBUG = False`?

Comment: Да, они имеются

Comment: static отдаётся? media отдаётся (там ошибка в `root`)?

Comment: у вас грамматические ошибки: djnago, meida...или это так и задумано?

Comment: А точно, ошибки это. Спасибо за помощь